# How to calculate running sum with reset in hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I came across a problem, I would like to perform a running sum of values, but with setting the threshold to sum = 100 i.e. when the sum exceeds 100 we start summing from 0, for example for such data:

```
row_id  amount
1       20
2       30
3       60
4       70
5       90
6       10
7       120
8       110
9       40
10      30
```

the sum field should look like this:

```
row_id  amount  sum
1       20      20
2       30      50
3       60      110
4       70      70
5       90      160
6       10      10
7       120     130
8       110     110
9       40      40
10      30      70
```

Is there any way to do this in **Hive**?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this in Hive using a combination of window functions and conditional expressions. Hive supports window functions that allow you to perform calculations over a specific range of rows, and conditional expressions enable you to set the threshold and reset the sum when it exceeds 100.

Assuming you have a Hive table called your_table with columns row_id and amount, you can add the sum column as follows:

```
-- Create a temporary table with running sum
CREATE TABLE temp_running_sum AS
SELECT
  row_id,
  amount,
  SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) AS running_sum
FROM
  your_table;

-- Calculate the final sum using conditional expressions
SELECT
  row_id,
  amount,
  CASE
    WHEN running_sum > 100 THEN amount
    ELSE running_sum
  END AS sum
FROM
  temp_running_sum;
```

This query first calculates the running sum using the SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) window function. The temporary table temp_running_sum will contain the row_id, amount, and running_sum columns. Then, in the final SELECT statement, we use a conditional expression to check if the running_sum is greater than 100. If it is, we reset the sum to the amount, otherwise, we keep the running_sum.

The output will be similar to the example you provided:

```
row_id amount sum
1      20     20
2      30     50
3      60     110
4      70     70
5      90     160
6      10     10
7      120    130
8      110    110
9      40     40
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't solve the problem because after reaching sum = 100 I don't want to insert the amount field as sum only to continue running sum on the amount field. So the running sum should reset every time it reaches 100.
So if there was row_id 10 with the amount of 30 - running_sum should equal 70 (40 from row 9 plus 30 from row 10)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with r as(
  select 1 lvl,row_id,amount,amount rsum
  from test 
  where row_id=( select min(row_id) from test)
union all
  select lvl +1,t.row_id,t.amount
    ,case when r.rsum>100 then t.amount else r.rsum+t.amount end rsum
  from r inner join test t on t.row_id=(r.row_id+1)
)
```